# Prevent backspace if carret is in the beginning of paragraph in tinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

I need to prevent backspace if my cursor position is in the beginning of the first paragraph. The whole thing is that I want to prevent the deletion of my first paragraph in the editor.

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: So far I detect when the user is in first paragraph but I cant find way to detect when the carret is in the beginning of the first paragraph - that's the big problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do (using Tinymce3) something like

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    ...
    setup : function(ed) {

        ed.onKeyDown.add(function(ed, event) {

            var range = ed.selection.getRng();

            // case: first editor node is the node with the caret in it
            if (range.startOffset == 0 && ed.getBody().getNode() == ed.getBody().firstChild)
            {
               event.preventDefault;
               return false;

            }
        });
    }
});
```

Since TinyMCE 4x keydown, keypress and keyup all became events of editor.on, the same result can be achieved doing the following:

```
ed.on('keydown', function( args ) {

  var range = ed.selection.getRng();

     // First editor node is the node with the caret in it
     if ( range.startOffset === 0 ) {
       event.preventDefault();
       return false;
     }

 });
```

Comment: OK this will prevent the event if I'm in first paragraph, but I need to prevent it only if my caret is in the beginning because i want to allow the user to have backspace, but i dont want to allow him to delete the first paragraph when he reaches it's beginning with the backspace key

Comment: Thank you my friend! You're helping me not for first time! It's working perfectly!

Comment: glad to have been able to help

Comment: is there a place i can hand jam this in on minified version of tinyMCE (its built into drupal 7 wysiwyg module)

Comment: @Tremor: You would have to download the tinymce developer version of the tinymce version your Drupal7 is using. THen apply your changes to the source code and build the tinymce souces new as you can read in the readme file.